# How can I start/open a jnlp from Chrome packaged apps?

Tags: java-web-start, jnlp, google-chrome-app

I am trying to open a Java web start application (jnlp) from a Chrome packaged app. I've tried to create an iframe (webframe) that contains a link to a jnlp but the jnlp doesn't get downloaded if Chrome browser isn't opened. I also tried to create a link to a local relative jnlp file but the outcome is the same.

Could somebody help me?
Thank you